# Why does my code return wrong sum when i concatenate it?

Tags: php

Cant figure out why my code wont return the sum properly if its concatenated with label tag.
But it can generate sum properly if on separate echos

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['num1'])&&!empty($_POST['num2']))
        {
            $a = $_POST['num1'];
            $b = $_POST['num2'];

            //this works
            echo '<label id="sumLabel"> sum = ';
            echo $a+$b;
            echo '</label>';

            //this doesnt work
            //why wont this code display num of a and b?
            //instead it returns just value of b
            //isnt my code above just the same as this?
            echo '<label id="sumLabel"> sum = ' . $a+$b . '</label>'; 
        }
        else {
            echo 'PLEASE INPUT num1 num2';
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because concatenation and sum have the same precedence. Also they are left associated.

So operations execute in that order:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
echo ((('<label id="sumLabel"> sum = ' . $a) + $b) . '</label>');
// results
// first concatenation                 ^'<label id="sumLabel"> sum = 1'
// summing                                   ^ 2
// second concatenation, final result              ^ '2</label>'
```

Let's explore it.

1. `'<label id="sumLabel"> sum = ' . 1` -> integer converts to string, then concatenates with other string -> `'<label id="sumLabel"> sum = 1'`
2. `'<label id="sumLabel"> sum = 1' + 2` ->string converts to integer (which gives 0) and sums with other integer -> 2
3. `2 . '</label>'` -> like the first one, integer converts to string, then concatenates with other string -> `'2</label>'`.

To avoid this you could add parentheses.

```
echo '<label id="sumLabel"> sum = ' . ($a+$b) . '</label>';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: @JericRodrigoTibayan , check spelling of `concatenation` word. And read updated answer. % )

Comment: Thanks sectus. Now I see thats why it wont work properly. Great link btw.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Sum the variable inside parenthesis `()`. Try this..

```
echo '<label id="sumLabel"> sum = ' . ($a+$b) . '</label>';
```